# How to make a border follow rounded corners on an image

Tags: css, border, rounded-corners

I want to have a circle image with a border, so I used this:

```
img {
    border: solid 10px #141313;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

But the border appears for the original shape of the border, square. Is it possible to have the border rounded too

I want to use `img` tag, not `background-image`

Comment: `border-radius` works as expected; just remember that some browsers need a vendor prefix in order to work;

Comment: Did anyone actually bother to read the question?? I didn't put prefixes to keep the question simple. no it does not works as "expected" the `img` is rounded, the border not. also I asked about `img` element not a div with `background-image`

Comment: your code works fine... i made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qkUJT/... Is there something that i missed out in fiddle??

Comment: @Usman seems to be a browser inconsistency/bug; as far as I can see it works in recent Webkit and Gecko browsers, but not for example in the current Opera (I don't know about IE);

Comment: @feeela... llyaD told in the reply of 'Ascension' that "The question has nothing to do with prefixes..."..thats why i am asking this ...

Comment: @feeela Yes, there seems to be a weired behavior, in latest chrome & canary the border is square, when in FF it is round (and I mean only the border, the corners are round in all browsers)

Comment: OT: I never heard of a browser or engine named "canary". What is this?

Comment: it's Chrome test builds in a separate install https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs/

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this article?

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1002-how-to-set-a-rounded-border-around-an-image-using-css/

Seems like you are missing some attributes for cross browser consistency at least ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Look: Only the border-radius property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera.

```
img {
    -moz-border-radius: 35px; // Mozilla
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px; // Chrome and Safari
    -o-border-radius: 35px; // Opera
    border-radius: 35px; // CSS 3
    }
```

Comment: Add high heigth and high width for create a circle.

Comment: to create a full circle you use `border-radius: 50%;` and equal width & height. The question has nothing to do with prefixes, I know about them, I removed them to simplify the question.

Comment: I know. But your use is good for each browser to work like your own way.

Comment: @IlyaD, sorry, but the only way is leaving the rounded image and then set the edges css. I do not know another way.